# Open source software or Matlab toolboxes for simulation of pulse chirping

Tags: resource-recommendations, laser, simulations, software, chirp

I am trying to simulate the effect on the waveform of pulse chirping a Gaussian pulse from a femtosecond laser by various mechanisms (e.g. prism, grating, grism, fiber optical cables).

I have tried producing my own simulations in Matlab without much success. Does anyone have any recommendations for free/open source software or Matlab toolboxes that would facilitate such a simulation?

Alternatively, if anyone can recommend any resources that give a thorough introductory discussion of the chirping used in pulsed chirp amplification, I would appreciate that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for software and not about physics (computational or otherwise).

Comment: It is not clear if you just want to create a chirped pulse, which I perceive as trivial, or simulation the physics of the prisms, etc, and all the other items and their effect on the pulse.  If the former it would help to see what you've tried so far (show some pseudo code) if the later try Zmax.

Comment: It is the latter. We wish to chirp a 35 fs pulse to a length of ~100 ps for use with a photocathode. I would like to be able to examine the effect the chirping would have on the resulting electron bunch. I will look into Zmax. Thanks for the recommendation.